# HIVE Time conversion issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, unix-timestamp, dst

We are getting a time from src "2019-11-03 01:01:00". 2019-11-03  is the day light saving day. 
lets say this is the end_time. We have another column in hive table start_time.
Logic to derive start time is :
`start_time = (end_time- 3600)`

### Issue ##:

When we apply the same logic during the job execution with `unix_timestamp()`, following are the results.

```
Start_time =
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-11-03 01:01:00') - 3600 ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
+----------------------+--+
|         _c0          |
+----------------------+--+
| 2019-11-03 01:01:00  |
+----------------------+--+
```

also

```
End_time = select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-11-03 01:01:00') ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

+----------------------+--+
|         _c0          |
+----------------------+--+
| 2019-11-03 01:01:00  |
+----------------------+--+
```

Both are returning the same result. This way our `start_date`=`end_date` which is not expected. 
We want the `End_time = "2019-11-03 00:01:00"`
Can someone help!

Comment: this bug is not resolved yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14305

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting this issue [HIVE-14305](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14305)

The solution can be to calculate date in bash and pass it to your script as a variable:

```
initial_date="2019-11-03 01:01:00"
datesec="$(date '+%s' --date="$initial_date")"
result_date=$( date --date="@$((datesec - 3600))" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
echo $result_date

#result 2019-11-03 00:01:00

#call your script like this

hive -hiveconf result_date="$result_date" -f script_name

#In the script use '${hiveconf:result_date}'
```